# Use npm to reuse react components between web parts

Tags: web-part, spfx, share, reusable, npm

I've been building web parts for a while now and I've found myself copy-pasting some of my spfx react components more often than I'd like.

The ideal solution for me here would be to publish the components I want to reuse to my private npm registry. This way I would be able to simply do a npm install my-component to add it to my current web part. This would also take care of versions for me.

The thing is I found 1 or 2 tutorials on how to do this but nothing using the spfx framework. As anybody every done this before? I'm not really hopping for a yeoman spfx-component-generator because I know there is none, but is there any skeleton project for that or any tips would help actually.

Thanks!

Comment: Refer this link. May be this will guide you -- https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/guidance/tutorial-share-data-between-web-parts-global-variable